# Converting wostringstream to wchar_t* Garbles Values

Tags: c++, string, unicode

I'm trying to generate a string and assign it to a `wchar_t*` but something seems to be garbling the string when I go to assign it.  Here's a simplified repro:

```
wostringstream woss;
woss << L"Test String";

// A: this doesn't work:
const wchar_t* foo = woss.str().c_str();
wcout << foo << endl; // "????????????????????????"

// B: this works:
wstring bar = woss.str();
const wchar_t* foo = foo.c_str();
wcout << foo << endl; // "Test String"

// C: this also works!?:
const wchar_t* foo = woss.str().c_str();
wstring bar = woss.str();
wcout << foo << endl; // "Test String"
```

When I do the conversion all at once (as in *A*), the resulting values pointed to by `foo` are a bunch of `0xFEEE` characters.  If I do it step by step however (as in *B*), the string ends up fine.  The weirdest thing is that if, *after* the assignment, I evaluate `woss.str()`, the data pointed to by `foo` suddenly becomes valid (as in *C*).

This leads me to think that somehow the chained assignment is returning a pointer to where the characters will eventually go, but it's somehow skipping the actual evaluation of `str()` and so isn't actually populating the values there.  Only once I call `str()` (either before or after the pointer assingment) does the data end up in the right place.  The thing is, I have no idea what would cause this behavior...

In case it's relevant, this is all running on a secondary thread, but I wouldn't expect that to matter since I'm only dealing with local variables.  Thoughts?

Comment: just one word. read http://utf8everywhere.org

Comment: @PavelRadzivilovsky In reality this code was populating a Win32 `LPCTSRT` struct member, so unfortunately must use wide chars.  Still, good article.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `wostringstream::str()` method returns a `std::wstring` *by value*.  You are not assigning that to anything, so its lifetime is temporary and ends when the expression is finished.  You are calling `std::wstring::c_str()` to save a pointer to the temporary's data, then the temporary gets destructed afterwards, leaving you with a stray pointer, thus causing [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your subsequent code.

Instead of saving the `std::wstring`'s data pointer, save the actual `std::wstring` object, and retrieve its data pointer only when actually needed.

Comment: So in a nutshell, *B* is the correct pattern to use.  I've always used the chained method in the past but I guess that was only ever in the context of a function call argument, so the pointer is valid until the call returns.